# Horizontal barchart with facet_grid, free_x not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the `mpg` dataset as an example, I want to use `facet_grid()` where the only the relevant models are listed under each manufacturer.

This code seems to work (left chart)

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(cty, model, data=mpg) +
  facet_grid(manufacturer ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free")
```

But this one doesn't (right)

```
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = model, y = cty), stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(manufacturer ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[image]

I saw this thread but couldn't get it to work:
[Horizontal bar chart with facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424282/horizontal-bar-chart-with-facets)

Thoughts?

Comment: maybe relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560858/using-coord-flip-with-facet-wrapscales-free-y-in-ggplot2-seems-to-give-u , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052000/in-ggplot2-coord-flip-and-free-scales-dont-work-together , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811038/removing-y-categorical-variables-facet-grid

Comment: Thanks. Saw this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940521/combining-horizonal-bars-with-facet-grid-in-ggplot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: `space="free"` and `scales="free"` don't work with `coord_flip`. Instead, use `geom_barh` (horizontal bar geom) from the `ggstance` package, which avoids the need for `coord_flip`. Details below.

`space="free"` and `scales="free"` don't work with `coord_flip`. This doesn't matter for plotting points, because with points you can switch the x and y axes and `geom_point` will still work, avoiding the need for `coord_flip`. However, `geom_bar` expects the value to be the `y` variable and the categories to be the `x` variable, so you need to use `coord_flip` to get horizontal bars.

To avoid `coord_flip`, you can use the horizontal geom `geom_barh` from the `ggstance` package, so that the `free` space and scales settings in `facet_grid` will work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(data=mpg, aes(x=cty, y=model)) +
  geom_barh(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(manufacturer ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")
```

Note that the code above creates a stacked bar plot, where the values of `cty` mpg for all the cars of a given `model` are stacked one on top of the other, which is non-sensical. You can see this if, for example, you set `colour="green"` inside `geom_barh`. I assume this plot is just for illustration but I wanted to point that out for completeness.

[image]

Comment: Well, @BenBolker, I consider this a public service to the R Community, since it frees up your time for more important things like adding new features to `lme4`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the solution. And yes, good eye about the cty variable. The example was for illustration only.